# How to add a contact to Ethereum Wallet?

Tags: mist, wallets, addresses, public-key

I'd like to add the addresses of my contacts to Ethereum Wallet, so I could send them eth and Dentacoin tokens, easily. I could also check their balances and check if they got the money.
How to add a new "read-only" contact without private key?

Answer (score 2):

I looked for the easiest solution, so that even beginners could add contacts in Ethereum Wallet as long as this feature is not implemented officially.

Here's how to:

1. Create a new text file and name it "Add_new_Ethereum_contact"
2. Paste following text in that file:

   {"address":

   "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

   ,"version":3,"id":"","Crypto":{"ciphertext":"","cipherparams":{"iv":""},"cipher":"aes-128-ctr","kdf":"scrypt","kdfparams":{"dklen":32,"salt":"","n":1024,"r":8,"p":1},"mac":""}}

Now, each time you want to add a new contact do:

1. Replace 0x0... in the text file with the eth address of your contact
2. Save the text file and open Ethereum Wallet
3. Go to Accounts -> Import Account (or hit cmd+i on a Mac)
4. Drag and drop the text file to "Drop wallet file"
5. Optional: Rename the added "AccountX" to your contacts name